# jQuery on('change') logic behaving wierdly in ios 8.2/8.3

Tags: jquery, ios, safari, mobile-safari, addclass

***I am facing a weird behavior of jQuery logic in mobile-safari*** (in ios 8.2/8.3 and 4.1), which works **fine in** **chrome, mozilla and ie**.

**My Requirement**: I have a list checkboxes, from which I can choose only one at a time like a radio button(its my requirement).
There are four buttons(**CREATE,VIEW,EDIT,DELETE**) corresponding to every checkbox provided.

When any of the checkbox is **checked**,I am **disabling** CREATE-button and enabling VIEW,EDIT,DELETE buttons and

If any of the checkbox is **unchecked** I am **enabling** CREATE-button and disabling VIEW/EDIT/DELETE buttons, for which I have written code below:

> CREATE-button class name: 'disable-on-check'
>
> VIEW/EDIT/DELETE buttons class name: 'enable-on-check'

```
$(':checkbox').on('change',function(){ 
var curr = $(this);                  
if(curr.is(':checked')){            
    $(".enable-on-check").addClass("click-enabled").removeClass("click-disabled");
    $(".disable-on-check").removeClass("click-enabled").addClass("click-disabled");                               
    $('.chkbx').prop("checked",false); //to make checkbox to behave like a radio button
    $(this).prop("checked",true);  //to make checkbox to behave like a radio button                             
}
else{
    $(".enable-on-check").removeClass("click-enabled").addClass("click-disabled");
    $(".disable-on-check").removeClass("click-disabled").addClass("click-enabled");
} });
```

**My Problem**: In mobile-safari (ios 8.2/8.3 and 4.1 as well)
when I **check** any of the checkboxes(more than twice or thrice), CREATE-button is getting highlighted **instead of** VIEW/EDIT /DELETE buttons and

If I **uncheck** any of the checkboxes VIEW/EDIT/DELETE buttons are getting enabled **instead of** CREATE-button -- which is exactly **inverse behaviour** of my logic.

Please help me, why I am getting this problem only in mobile-safari ??
THANKS IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lot of trails, changing the event type helped me in fixing the issue.

What I observed in my experience is **.on('change')** is invoking my logic twice at some instance(don't know why). So I tried with **.on('keydown click')** and now everything is working fine :)

Finally the answer is:

```
$(':checkbox').on('keydown click',function(){ 
var curr = $(this);                  
if(curr.is(':checked')){            
    $(".enable-on-check").addClass("click-enabled").removeClass("click-disabled");
    $(".disable-on-check").removeClass("click-enabled").addClass("click-disabled");                               
    $('.chkbx').prop("checked",false); //to make checkbox to behave like a radio button
    $(this).prop("checked",true);  //to make checkbox to behave like a radio button                             
}
else{
    $(".enable-on-check").removeClass("click-enabled").addClass("click-disabled");
    $(".disable-on-check").removeClass("click-disabled").addClass("click-enabled");
} });
```